# Adding dependency to mysql-connector-java causes NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(I) in my Play framework2 app

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0

As the title states I have added mysql dependency:

```
    val appName         = "report"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-analytics" % "v3-rev15-1.8.0-beta",
      "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson2" % "1.11.0-beta",
      "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-jetty" % "1.11.0-beta",
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
     )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
      resolvers += "Google Analytics" at "http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg"
    )
```

This causes:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(I)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;

I guess there is something in the mysql dependencies that gets rid of that method...
But what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually means that the JAR version has method signatures that don't match what's in the calling code.  Check the version of the CacheBuilder JAR.  You might be out of synch.

Answer (score -1):

Ok found it!

First of all I needed to updated Guava since Guava 11 changed:

```
CacheBuilder#maximumSize(int) has been replaced with CacheBuilder#maximumSize(long)
```

So I updated Guava to the newest release 13.0.1 but I still got the error. This since 
reflections was still wrong. Changed reflections to 0.9.8 and everything works as expected.

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
      "com.google.apis" % "google-api-services-analytics" % "v3-rev15-1.8.0-beta",
      "com.google.http-client" % "google-http-client-jackson2" % "1.11.0-beta",
      "com.google.oauth-client" % "google-oauth-client-jetty" % "1.11.0-beta",
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
      "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.8",
      "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "13.0.1"
     )
```

Comment: This reminds me of that joke about an Irishman named Seamus who was driving in New York, looking for a parking space.  There were none to be had, so he said "God, if you can find me a space I promise I'll give up the whiskey and start going to church every week."  A spot miraculously opened up as he finished his prayer.  He smiled, looked skyward, and said "Nevermind!  I found one!"

Comment: Haha good one! =) I would of course mark your answer if I thought it was good enough for other developers with the same problem. Isn't it better to have a more precise answer than just a hint? If you disagree I will gladly change the correct answer mark.

Comment: You mijght not understand the joke: I did give you more than a hint.  The step that got you past the issue in your question was what I told you to do.  The JARs in your app, for Guava and reflections, were not correct.  The hint was all that could be given based on your question.  You can change your response as you see fit.